# Return object created on POST - express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
router.route('/vehicles')
.post(function (req, res) {
    var vehicle = new Vehicle();

    vehicle.make = req.body.make;
    vehicle.model = req.body.model;
    vehicle.color = req.body.color;

    vehicle.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json({message: 'Vehicle was successfully added', make: req.body.make, model: req.body.model, color: req.body.color});
    });
})
```

As you can see by adding this: `make: req.body.make, model: req.body.model, color: req.body.color` I was able to successfully return the posted object.

However, that's not quite what I need, besides returning the newly created object I also need to return the id of the newly created object.

How can I do this?

Comment: How about res.json ({message: 'Vehicle was successfully added', ...vehicle});

Comment: I definitely wouldn't bother with a server-side-generated "success" message. The HTTP 200 response code should be sufficient. Speaking of, your error state should probably include an error status, ie `return res.status(500).send(err)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shorten the whole thing like so:

```
router.route('/vehicles')
.post(function (req, res) {
    var vehicle = new Vehicle(req.body);

    vehicle.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err);
        }
        vehicle.message = 'Vehicle was successfully added';
        res.json(vehicle);
    });
});
```

I'm assuming you're using mongoose, based on the other syntax in your question.

Comment: If you get an error with this setup, there will be an additional error about not sending headers again. You need to return the first `res.send(error)`

Comment: Thanks, I just copied his code without noticing that. Fixed.